# Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined ,i dont understand what's wrong

Tags: javascript

```
let count = 0;
const value = document.querySelector("#value");
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
btns.forEach(function(btn){
        btns[0].addEventListener('click',function(e){
            const styles = console.log(e.currentTarget.classList);
            if(styles.contains("btn")){ //Error
                count++;
            }
```

dont know why it says that it can't be read as property Is the contains property not working anymore or what ? How's that Underfined ? ?

Comment: you probably mean: `const styles = e.currentTarget.classList; console.log(styles);
            if(styles.contains("btn")){ //Error
                count++;
            }`

Comment: `console.log` returns undefined

Answer (score 2):

Because [`console.log` has no return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log).  So this sets `styles` to `undefined`:

```
const styles = console.log(e.currentTarget.classList);
```

If you just want to check the values in `e.currentTarget.classList` then just do that:

```
if(e.currentTarget.classList.contains("btn")) {
    count++;
}
```

There's no need for the additional variable here, and certainly no need to use `console.log` when setting that variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you are assigning value to `styles` variable you are writing console.log instead it should be only `const styles = e.currentTarget.classList;`
The debugged code should look like this:-

```
let count = 0;
const value = document.querySelector("#value");
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
btns.forEach(function(btn){
        btns[0].addEventListener('click',function(e){
            const styles = e.currentTarget.classList;
            if(styles.contains("btn")){ //Error
                count++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) for the handler. Second, if you want to count the number of `button.btn` you can use `document.querySelectorAll`. Third: `console.log` does not return anything, so `styles` from `console.log(e.currentTarget.classList)` will be `undefined`.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", btnDemo);

const nOfButtonsWithClassBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn").length;
console.log(`number of button.btn ${nOfButtonsWithClassBtn}`);

function btnDemo(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target.closest("button");
  if (origin) {
    console.clear();
    if (evt.target.classList.contains("btn")) {
      console.log("you clicked a button.btn element!");
    } else if (evt.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
      console.log("you indeed clicked a button, but it does not has class .btn");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">btn1</button>
<button class="btn">btn2</button>
<button>Not .btn</button>
<p>Click won't do anything<p>
```